# Android - Uploading from camera works in webview but uploading from gallery does not

Tags: android, webview, upload, gallery

I have done massive searching on this subject and up until about 30 minutes ago I could not get the file chooser or camera to even open in the app.

Now I am able to get them to open when clicking the upload button. The camera uploads work, so I take a picture, save it, and its added to my apps queue to be uploaded.

The problem is when choosing a file from the gallery, it does not get added to the app queue for upload. Can someone please assist with this?

Update: I have also noticed that. I can choose the picture I took with the camera and reupload that as much as I want from the file manager/gallery. It just wont let me upload anything from the filemanager/gallery that I did not take with the camera.

Here is my `MainActivity` Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private WebView webView;
private String urlStart = "http://www.xxxxx.com/";

//File choser parameters
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE   = 2888;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;

//Camera parameters
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webView.loadUrl(urlStart);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try{
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                        File.separator + "browser-photos");
                cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
                String mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath));

                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[] { cameraIntent });

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        // For Android < 3.0
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg ) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // For Android  > 4.1.1
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }



        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
            onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
            return true;
        }
        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
            Log.d("androidruntime", "www.xxxxxx.com: " + message);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
    {

        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;
        }

        Uri result=null;

        try{
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                result = null;

            } else {

                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

    }
}}
```

Comment: This was resolved in the websites code, it was not a problem with the above code.

Comment: May I know how you solved it in the websites code.. I am running with the same issue