# upload image from camera in webview does not work

Tags: android, image, webview

I've been trying to do an upload of images in Workplace from facebook through webview from gallery and from camera.

From gallery it works fine but from camera the image doesn't appear on the upload.

I've seen similar posts with this question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725814/upload-an-image-from-camera-or-gallery-in-webview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718874/android-uploading-from-camera-works-in-webview-but-uploading-from-gallery-does) but i don't see what's wrong.

This is my class:

```
public class WorkplaceActivity extends BaseActivity implements WorkplaceContract.View {

private WorkplacePresenter workplacePresenter;
private Tracker trackerGA;
private MyApplicaton appGA;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private WebView ctWebView;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private Uri mCameraURI;

@Override
public void setupWorkplace() {
    WebViewClient webclient = new WebViewClient();

    ctWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ctWebView);
    ctWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    ctWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ctWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ctWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    ctWebView.setWebViewClient(webclient);
    ctWebView.loadUrl(ConstantsStrings.WORKPLACE_URL);
}

@Override
public void setupGA() {
    // Google Analytics
    appGA = (MyApplicaton) getApplication();
    trackerGA = appGA.getDefaultTracker();
    sendGA(ConstantsStrings.WORKPLACE_GA_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workplace);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    workplacePresenter = new WorkplacePresenter();
    workplacePresenter.attachView(this);
    workplacePresenter.checkPermissions(WorkplaceActivity.this);

    ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left);
        actionBar.setTitle("");

        // add back button
        ImageButton back_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ctWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    ctWebView.goBack();
                }

                Log.d("WORKPLACE", "click back");
            }
        });

        // add close button
        ImageButton close_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        close_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();

                Log.d("WORKPLACE", "click close");
            }
        });

    }

    setupGA();
    setupWorkplace();
    ctWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            WorkplaceActivity.this.openFileChooser(filePathCallback);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (mUploadMessage != null) {
            Uri[] temp = new Uri[1];
            if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {
                temp[0] = intent.getData();
            } else if (mCameraURI != null) {
                temp[0] = mCameraURI;
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(temp);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
}

public static Intent newInstance(Context context) {
    return new Intent(context, WorkplaceActivity.class);
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    workplacePresenter.attachView(this);
}

@Override
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    workplacePresenter.detachView();
}

@Override
public void showLoading() {
}

@Override
public void hideLoading() {
}

@Override
public void sendGA(String msg) {
    // Google Analytics
    trackerGA = appGA.getDefaultTracker();
    trackerGA.setScreenName(msg);
    trackerGA.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}

private void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg) {
    mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

    try {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WorkplaceActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WorkplaceActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission_group.STORAGE}, 6);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(WorkplaceActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 5);
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File cameraDir = new File(storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "browser-photos");
        cameraDir.mkdirs();
        String mCameraFilePath = cameraDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + ".jpg";
        mCameraURI = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath));
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCameraURI);


        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{takePictureIntent});

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Camera Exception:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

When i do try to upload an image from the camera, my phone saves the image but it does not appear on the upload screen.

Answer (score 0):

check this it's worked for me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessages;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + webView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");

        webView.loadUrl("url");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            // For api level bellow 24
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                    // Return false means, web view will handle the link
                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            }


            // From api level 24
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                /*Toast.makeText(mcontext, "New Method",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                // Get the tel: url
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();

                if (url.startsWith("http")) {
                    // Return false means, web view will handle the link
                    return false;
                }

                return false;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                openImageChooser();
            }

            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices

            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                mUploadMessages = filePathCallback;
                openImageChooser();
                return true;
            }

            // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
            }

            //openFileChooser for other Android versions

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
            }
        });

    }

    private void openImageChooser() {
        try {

            File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "FolderName");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage && null == this.mUploadMessages) {
                return;
            }

           /* Uri result;
            if (requestCode != RESULT_OK){
                result = null;
            }else {
                result = intent == null ? this.mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
            }
            this.mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            this.mUploadMessage = null;*/
            if (null != mUploadMessage) {
                handleUploadMessage(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

            } else if (mUploadMessages != null) {
                handleUploadMessages(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleUploadMessage(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Uri result = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                result = null;
            } else {
                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null

                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void handleUploadMessages(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        Uri[] results = null;
        try {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                results = null;
            } else {
                if (intent != null) {
                    String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                    ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
                    if (clipData != null) {
                        results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                            results[i] = item.getUri();
                        }
                    }
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                } else {
                    results = new Uri[]{mCapturedImageURI};
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mUploadMessages.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUploadMessages = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add storage and camera permission in manifest as well as programmatically.